# Strange behavior when plotting Floor or Ceiling function

Tags: plotting

Why the following two codes plot different graphs?

```
Plot[Floor[x], {x, -5, 5}]
Plot[Floor[x] /. a -> b, {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image: graphs where the second plot has joins]

a and b did not have any assigned value.

It is same for Floor, Ceiling, Round and IntegerPart... all are stepwise function.
But for example we have another stepwise function PrimePi and the graphs are same for both cases.

What is wrong with Mathematica? Notice that "`/. a -> b`" does nothing at all, you can replace it with anything as long the "`/.`" is there.

Comment: This is determined by the [`Exclusions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html) option. The function you plot has 2 new variables so it doesn't know what not to plot.

Comment: It is not because of variables a and b. You can also have this: Plot[Floor[x] /. (1 -> 1), {x, -5, 5}]

Comment: Definitely it has something to do with Exclusions, but all stepwise functions should behave the same when plotted. Why is PrimePi treated different than Floor?

Comment: You're right; that's definitely an interesting corner case!

Comment: It may have to do with the `HoldAll` attribute of `Plot`. `Plot[Evaluate[func[x] /. a -> b], {x, -5, 5}]` plots the same as `Plot[Floor[x], {x, -5, 5}]`. Presumably, the `HoldAll` prevents the automatic application of the `Exclusions` with the exception of the `PrimePi` case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exclusions mechanism avoids inputs that appear to be "programmatic", which includes the following general categories (and a few others):

- numeric solvers: `NIntegrate`, `FindMinimum`, `NDSolve`, ...
- looping constructs: `Map`, `Table`, `While`, `Nest`, ...
- assignments: `Set`, `Increment`, ...
- replacements: `Replace`, `ReplaceAll`, ...
- "functions": `CompiledFunction`, `InterpolatingFunction`, ...